# Uniqueness of a linear map

Tags: linear-transformations

Let V be a vector space. $\dim V = n$ and $ 0 \ne \alpha \in V$. Then 
$\forall \beta \in V$ $\exists T: V \longrightarrow V$ s.t. $T(\alpha) = \beta$

My thoughts:

> **Theorem** (from Schaum's Linear Algebra) Let $V$ and $U$ be vector spaces and $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ be a basis on $V$. Let $\{u_1,\ldots, u_n\}$ be arbitrary vectors in $U$. Then there exists a unique linear mapping $F: V \to U$ such that $F(v_i) = u_i$.

So I think this statement is wrong because of the uniqueness.

Can someone confirm or fix me if i'm wrong?(T must be linear V is finite dimensional)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are $u_i$ and $v_i$? $T$ must be linear? $V$ is finite-dimensional?

Comment: You have to put other hypothesis on $u_i$, otherwise your theorem is false

Comment: @Exodd, no hypotheses are needed on $u_i$. Only on $v_i$.

Comment: @lhf the author switched $u_i$ and $v_i$ in the last edit

Comment: @Exodd I sat 1 hour on this and i'm still struggling I would like to get some help. I start thinking that the statement is correct. I tried to do it by the complementary way. but I have no idea what does T($\alpha$) $\ne$ $\beta$ tells me

Comment: @mdave16 I sat 1 hour on this and i'm still struggling I would like to get some help. I start thinking that the statement is correct. I tried to do it by the complementary way. but I have no idea what does T($\alpha$) $\ne$ $\beta$ tells me

Comment: @user21312, I also sat on this, and i agree with lhf, the theorem is true, but if $u_i$ are linearly independent, then $F$ is invertible (this is what i meant). Could you try and construct two distinct maps $F,G$ which send $v_i \mapsto u_i$ and see why you are wrong? -- Also we should really move this to chat, rather than having extended conversation in comments

Comment: @mdave16 I can see F,G will be forced to be the same linear map.

Comment: now that you've answered your own question, you could submit an answer to your own question

Answer (score 0):

The theorem you've quoted is the way to go.

Just note that $\alpha\ne0$ implies that $\alpha$ is part of a basis of $V$.

Indeed, let $v_1=\alpha$ and complete this to a basis $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ of $V$. 
Let $u_1=\beta$ and $u_2=u_3=\cdots=u_n=0$. 
Now apply the theorem.

Comment: I sat 1 hour on this and i'm still struggling I would like to get some help. I start thinking that the statement is correct. I tried to do it by the complementary way. but I have no idea what does T($\alpha$) $\ne$ $\beta$ tells me

Comment: @user21312 the statement is correct. You just have to see that $\alpha=v_1$ and $u_1=\beta$

Comment: @Exodd As I said i'm stuck on how I'm supposed to show that. the quantifer $\exists$ T s.t.....  doesn't let me move

Comment: @user21312 The theorem tells you that there exists F s.t. etc.etc. Just call it $T$

Comment: @Exodd So you're basically saying the theorem is the proof for that? I just need to change the F to T and v1 to alpha  and u1 to beta? I don't understand